# All finite products in a category

Tags: category-theory

Any tips on how to show that a category has all finite products? I have a homework to show that a specific category has all finite products and I don't know where to start. Any tips or hints?

Thanks

Comment: It is enough to prove that it has a terminal object and binary products. Based on that by induction it can be shown that it has $n$-ary products for every $n\in\{0,1,2,\dots\}$.

Comment: I don't know what category you have, but there are a lot of examples of concrete categories (i.e. categories where objects are sets with some structure and morphisms are functions which respect that structure) where the product of two objects is the cartesian product endowed with a reasonable "product structure". This could give you an idea of what a product looks like in your category.

Comment: thanks. I intentionally didn't tell which category it is since then I usually get a full answer on my problem and I would like to solve it myself....
Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa This is not the way to go: the context is very important for us to help you. If you don't want a full answer, just emphasize that in your question (write it in the beginning of the post, in bold, so that nobody can miss it).

Comment: in this case it was not causing any confusion. but I understand what you mean and I will do so in the future